# Apache showing the flowing error "Apache HTTP Server Has Stopped Working"

Tags: php, joomla, xampp, joomla3.0

Every time while running the application of joomla always it is showing 
 "Apache HTTP Server Has Stopped Working".
 My joomla version is as follows

```
Database Version         : 5.5.5-10.1.16-MariaDB
Database Collation       : latin1_swedish_ci
PHP Version              : 7.0.9
Web Server               : Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.9
Joomla! Version          : Joomla! 3.6.4 Stable 
Joomla! Platform Version : Joomla Platform 13.1.0 Stable
```

[image]

** only it work after  when we click **close the program** from the above dialog box. (Some time if we click **close the program** it will shown again , more than 5 or 6 times as in the above image after that it will work fine.

The Following error Displayed:

```
[Tue Nov 21 07:47:28.665233 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4428:tid 408] AH00428: Parent: child process 8268 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.
[Tue Nov 21 07:47:29.290256 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 4428:tid 408] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 21 07:47:29.321507 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4428:tid 408] AH00455: Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/7.0.18 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Nov 21 07:47:29.321507 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4428:tid 408] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec 17 2016 10:42:52
[Tue Nov 21 07:47:29.321507 2017] [core:notice] [pid 4428:tid 408] AH00094: Command line: 'd:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Nov 21 07:47:29.321507 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4428:tid 408] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3484
[Tue Nov 21 07:47:29.977746 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 3484:tid 408] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 21 07:47:30.384022 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 3484:tid 408] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 21 07:47:30.430895 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3484:tid 408] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Nov 21 07:47:37.930978 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4428:tid 408] AH00428: Parent: child process 3484 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.
[Tue Nov 21 07:47:38.571600 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 4428:tid 408] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 21 07:47:38.618476 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4428:tid 408] AH00455: Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/7.0.18 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Nov 21 07:47:38.618476 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4428:tid 408] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec 17 2016 10:42:52
[Tue Nov 21 07:47:38.618476 2017] [core:notice] [pid 4428:tid 408] AH00094: Command line: 'd:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Nov 21 07:47:38.618476 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4428:tid 408] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5520
[Tue Nov 21 07:47:39.134107 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5520:tid 412] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 21 07:47:39.368464 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5520:tid 412] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 21 07:47:39.415340 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5520:tid 412] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: What doe the problem details tell you? And you apache error logs?

Comment: why down vote.?

Comment: @Elin i ahve modified with the error log.

Comment: And what did you try once you searched for that set of error messages?  Your question needs to explain what research you have done.  At least explain why trying the answers to the other questions with that same error message did not work for you. Also think about what details you have left out, for example are you using XAMPP or anything like that? Did you set up a certificate?

Comment: all methods i try in stack over flow  and other helping sites of xampp and r related sites . so i didn't found any clear solution for this after trying every thing. at last only i posted in Stack overflow.

Comment: @Elin already i explained. what the error in (* ) mark. error will comes in between the site is working or after some idle. ( Some time i can see the port has been jumping to another port continuous, in the xampp)

Comment: So you tried changing ports, making sure you are admin, and making sure your certificate is correct? In your question, explain what you tried and what happened.   Is it possible something else is trying to use the same port? What happens if you browse to a static html page? I don't see how this could have anything to do with either joomla or phpmyadmin.

Comment: i don't trying changing port i put one static port for this. but some time it is changing automatically..

Comment: For most of the search responses to this problem changing the port (often because of a conflict with Skype) is the fix, so I have to say I question whether you have actually tried the suggestions in other posts about this error message.

Comment: already i said, i already tried all solutions around 85 post i read :
all methods i try in stack over flow and other helping sites of xampp and the related sites . so i didn't found any clear solution for this after trying every thing. at last only i posted in Stack overflow.

Comment: I think you should ask this question on Server Fault.